# Setting the variables of an object using a switch statement

Tags: java

Sorry if I phrased the question badly.

I have an `Enemy` class that has a method that sets its variables.

```
public void initEnemy(String enemy){
        switch (enemy){
            case "Gwalchavad":
                name = "Gwalchavad";
                hp = 50;
                atk = 3;
                break;
            case "Charlemagne":
                name = "Charlemagne";
                hp = 100;
                atk = 5;
                break;
            case "Diabolos":
                name = "Diabolos";
                hp = 150;
                atk = 9;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I call `initEnemy()` in my `Engine` class.

```
Enemy e = new Enemy();
...
public void startGame(String difficulty){
        switch (difficulty){
            case "easy":
                e.initEnemy("Gwalchavad");

                gw.lblEnemyName.setText(e.name);
                gw.lblEnemyHp.setText("HP: " + e.hp);
                gw.lblEnemyAtk.setText("ATK: " + e.atk);
                gw.lblEnemyImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameEngine.class.getResource("/res/imgs/soldier.png")));
                break;
            case "medium":
                e.initEnemy("Charlemagne");

                gw.lblEnemyName.setText(e.name);
                gw.lblEnemyHp.setText("HP: " + e.hp);
                gw.lblEnemyAtk.setText("ATK: " + e.atk);
                gw.lblEnemyImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameEngine.class.getResource("/res/imgs/knight.png")));
                break;
            case "hard":
                e.initEnemy("Diabolos");

                gw.lblEnemyName.setText(e.name);
                gw.lblEnemyHp.setText("HP: " + e.hp);
                gw.lblEnemyAtk.setText("ATK: " + e.atk);
                gw.lblEnemyImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameEngine.class.getResource("/res/imgs/demon.png")));
                break;
        }
    }
```

However, interacting with `Enemy e` returns errors that say its `name`, `hp`, and `atk` are null. The variables are set but only inside the specific switch-case and does not apply to outside of the switch. Is there a way so that it also affects the `Enemy` object outside the switch?

Comment: we don't know how your code is called, or what else happens. you should learn to use getters and setters, though, instead of just making/using all variables public. Can you provide an example in which we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with the code provided, filling in the missing parts until it could run. I don't see any issues and the fields are set as expected. The problem must be in code that isn't shown in the question. Read ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for advice.